# Is there any dictionary to look up for words that have similar vowel pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation, dictionaries

I would like to make smooth-sounding sentences and slogans, so it is important to me to find words with similar pronunciations.

Is there any dictionary that can help me find words like that?

Comment: You could try a *rhyming dictionary*.

Comment: Kenyon and Knott's _Pronouncing Dictionary of American English_ gives the pronunciations (only; nothing else) in [IPA-based phonemic notation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf). Match the notations and you match the sounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*slogan* rhymes with

> blowgun, bogan, brogan, cogan, crogan, dogan, gogan, grogan, hogan, kogan, logan, mogan, ogan, rogan, shogun, vogan, wogan

See: [RhymeZone](http://www.rhymezone.com/r/rhyme.cgi?Word=slogan&typeofrhyme=perfect&lycos=on&org1=syl&org2=l)

I know the OP actually likes to have pairs (or sets) of rhyming words, preferably [homophone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophone)s (*Raise, rays, rase, raze, rehs, réis, res*).

A "complete list of homophones in American English" is [here](http://www.homophone.com/results.php?how=begin&searchfor=A).

Comment: RhymeZone is what I need. Thank you @Kris so much!